# How to Fill List dynamically with Partial Views Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my web application User can Add New Tabs

```
TabModel 

{
public string TabName {get; set;}
public List<SubTabModel> Subs {get; set;}
}
```

Each Tab can contain List of SubTabs

```
SubTabModel
{
public string SubTabName {get ; set;}
}
```

How to perform usabilty of Adding Sub Tabs, and get fully functionality of Requirement attribute and Posting this Tab model with her SubTabs and proceed?

Comment: Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options

Answer (score 0):

```
SubTabModel
{
public string SubTabName {get ; set;}
public T RelatedModel {get ; set;}
}
```

You need to use generic related mvc model with you can apply Validations.
You can do like that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following will help you

**Partial View**

```
@model List<TabModel>

@{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <a>@item.TabName</a>
                @if (item.Subs != null)
                {
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var subItem in item.Subs)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a>@subItem.SubTabName</a>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

**Controller**

```
   return PartialView("PartialViewName", TabModel);
```

Comment: This logic don't allow me dynammicaly add SubTabs by User. It will work for showing it or editing. Because List also added. I want some logic like this`
Html.Textboxfor(m=>m.add(new SubModel{Name}) 
or somehow

Comment: @AlexandrSargsyan, Are you want to add new sub menu from partial view?

Comment: I want working tehcnic, maybe with partials maybe no, I do it with some jquery features like clone element , but problem, is that the cloning same partial view and change name indexes n to n+1 ex. : SubTabModel[0].Name  to Sub.TabModel[1].Name, it works fine, binding in model works and my list fill with two items, but in this case Requirement attribute works only for first element .